# Correct way to convert rvalue reference to temporary parameter to const lvalue return in C++

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, temporary-objects

I'm trying to implemenet find-like method to extract reference to value from container and return a default value if the value is not found or of an incompatible type.

```
template<class T> const T& get (key_type k, const T& def)
{
    const T* r = dynamic_cast<const T*> (find(k)); // suppose `find` returns a pointer to common base class or NULL if the key not found
    return r ? *r : def; 
}
```

this function works incorrectly if `def` is a temporary object:

```
const sometype& val = find(key, sometype(someargs));
```

So, is it possible to handle this case using rvalue reference and moving or copying the temporary object somehow?

```
template<class T> const T& get (key_type k, T&& def)
{
    const T* r = dynamic_cast<const T*> (find(k)); // suppose `find` returns a pointer to common base class or NULL if the key not found
    return r ? *r : std::move(def); // or copy? or something else?
}
```

`T`might be an abstract base class too. And, please, I'd prefer boost-free solution.

Comment: Any reason you don't do like the standard library does and return an iterator?  Then the calling code can inspect the iterator and if it doesn't equal the `end` iterator then it's valid to indirect through.

Comment: @NathanOliver, there would be a lot of repeating of this inspection over the project, so looking for a way to form a repeating code as a subprogram.

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to avoid that if you want to allow temporaries.  Temporary lifetime extension does not pass through functions so there is no way to get a lvalue from the rvalue you pass to the function.  You could disallow rvalues, but not sure if that would be acceptable.

Comment: If there was a way, it would be the default and only way to return stuff from functions, dontchathink? It is so convenient, just return a reference without thinking of lifetimes!

Comment: This is not perfect but could be acceptable solution, if there is no others. Would `template<class T> const T& get (key_type k, T&& def) = delete;` be enough or should I `delete` overloads to `const T&&` as well?

Comment: `get (key_type k, T&& def) = delete;` would be bad as it also stops you from taking in lvalues (thanks to reference collapsing rules).  I think `get (key_type k, const T&& def) = delete;` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. The temporary object is alive only for that statement and will be destroyed before you access it through the returned reference.

```
const sometype &val = get(not_existing_key, get_temporary_object());
do_something_with(val);
```

When you `do_something_with(val)`, the object to which the reference `val` is bound is already destroyed.
The `get` function should not called with a temporary object for the parameter `def`.
Instead, you can copy the temporary object to a variable, then call the function with the reference to the variable.

```
auto copied_object = get_temporary_object();
const sometype &val = get(not_existing_key, copied_object);
do_something_with(val);
```

Now, the object to which `val` is bound is in the variable `copied_object`.

Comment: I suppose C++ would not understand something like `get(not_existing_key, (auto copied_object = get_temporary_object));`? Probably in your answer should be `...get(not_existing_key, copied_object)`? Anyway I do not fully understand what exactly `std::move` and `std::copy` do to object than...